# filter following JSON using underscore

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a collection like this:

```
    var collection={
     "Today": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "iPod Nano",
    "image": "img/items/item1.jpg",
    "special": 0
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Samsung TV",
    "image": "img/items/item2.jpg",
    "special": 1
}],
"Monday 11 August 2014": [{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Nikon Camera",
    "image": "img/items/item3.jpg",
    "special": 0

}, {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "iPad 1000",
    "image": "img/items/item4.jpg",
    "special": 0

}],

"Monday 30 August 2014 ": [{

    "id": "5",

    "name": "ar of Gold",
    "mage": "img / items / item5.jpg ",
    "special ": 1

}, {
    "id ": "6 ",
    " name ": "Buzz Light Year ",
    "image ": " img / items / item6.jpg ",
    "special ": 1

}]

};
```

I'd like to filter collection and remain only special == 1 :

I tried:

```
 var Specials=_.reduce(collection,function(memo,item){
                var result = _.filter(item,function(c){
                    return c.special==0 ;
                });
                if(result.length > 0 ){
                    var newResult = {};
                    newResult.deals = result;
                    newResult.id = item.id;
                    memo = _.union(memo,newResult);
                }
                return memo;
            },[]); 
            var jsonText=JSON.stringify(Specials);

            console.log("=========>" + jsonText);
```

But didn't get what I've expected.

why?  I'd like result to be this:

```
var filtered={
"Today": [{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Samsung TV",
    "image": "img/items/item2.jpg",
    "special": 1
}],

"Monday 30 August 2014 ": [{

    "id": "5",

    "name": "ar of Gold",
    "mage": "img / items / item5.jpg ",
    "special ": 1

}, {
    "id ": "6 ",
    " name ": "Buzz Light Year ",
    "image ": " img / items / item6.jpg ",
    "special ": 1

}]

};
```

Comment: YOur json is not valid)

Comment: You say you want to filter on `c.special == 1` but your code is filtering on `c.special == 0` ... which one is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i remember reduce has a bit other functionality,

You can use **each** + **reject** if you need to keep same JSON structure [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R7x5N/)

```
_.each(collection, function(items, key){

    var filtered = _.reject(items, function(item){ 
        return item.special < 1 
    });

    if(filtered.length){
        specials[key] = filtered;
    }
});
```

Comment: what if I only keep those date which contains specials. and remove all other date tag which has no speicals.

Comment: I've update code in fiddle. or you can use code provided by @undefined

Comment: Hi, This is exactly what I expected.  Thanks.  I've learnt how to generate new JSON data by your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try by this:

```
   var collection = { 
  "Today": [
    {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "iPod Nano",
    "image": "img/items/item1.jpg",
     "special": 0
    }, 
    {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Samsung TV",
    "image": "img/items/item2.jpg",
    "special": 1
    }
],

"Monday 11 August 2014": [
    {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Nikon Camera",
    "image": "img/items/item3.jpg",
     "special": 0
    }, 
    {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "iPad 1000",
    "image": "img/items/item4.jpg",
     "special": 0
    }
]
```

};

```
for(var i in collection){
  collection[i] = _.filter(collection[i], function(item){
    return item.special == 0;
  });
}
console.log(collection);
```

The results will be grouped by day, if you want to merge you must write this

```
var res = [];
for(var j in collection){
  for(var i = 0; i < collection[j].length; i++)
    res.push(collection[j][i]);
}

console.log(res);
```

And [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6Pgpx/1/)

Comment: here is what I got: {
    "Today": [],
    "Monday 11 August 2014": [],
    "Monday 30 August 2014": []
}

Comment: Filter function returns empty array if there's now required objects.

Comment: Thanks. FUserThrowError

Comment: I think return item.special == 1; as I need ==1 filtered.

Comment: is it possible to delete empty tags if no data found, for example, if today has no special, don't show today in result JSON

Comment: Yes you can check, something like this: if(!item.special) return false; in filter function